# How to upload video into Odoo?

Tags: video, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-website

I would like to upload video(s) from my local storage, manually, on Odoo website but it seems that there is no such option.

When I try to upload any media, I see that I can upload image, document (e.g. pdf file). There is no problem to upload any image or pdf file but on video section, it is written: `Video code (URL or Embed)` and `Accepts Youtube, Vimeo, Dailymotion and Youku videos`. Why? Why is this not possible? Do you have any solution?

[image]

I especially am asking this because I want to play video on my carousel and when I insert a vimeo or youtube video, on mobile, I have the `Tap to Unmute` issue.

Ayn idea, solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after I did some researches I have found the solution of how to upload a video on Odoo.

In order to add any media, you first need to edit a page of the website on front-end. When you click to `Edit` you will see the new blocks and all edit options on the right sidebar. Then, click to an empty area in the page and you will see that `STYLE` section on sidebar will become active. Click to the image icon ("File/Image" when you hover it) and `Select a Media` modal will open. Go to `Document` section --> `Upload a document` --> choose video from your local storage and when the upload finishes, it will add/appear a small video icon on the empty area where you had clicked before. Right click on it and and copy the link. Then, remove the extra part of the link and that is it.

e.g.

```
www.yourdomain.com/web/content/111111/?unique=2323c304345b19d696a5cf1cabb05cc9da49a5d90&download=true
```

final result:

```
www.yourdomain.com/web/content/111111/
```